# How to redirect a page from '/' route to main '/dashboard' route automatically after first sign in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have auth.js page which decides which route to direct to after login.I am using ui-router for routing.Now the thing is after login user details are captured and the route accordingly changes.Here if I change the route from '/dashboard' to '/' and hit enter, then it first shows sign in page then redirects to dashboard which I don't want.If I go from '/dashboard' to '/' then it should automatically go to dashboard page without going to sign in page.How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have a ng-init in login page, which checks if logged in it should redirect to dashboard.

Comment: @Trying2Learn I am new to angular js and I may be wrong in this but  I am using controllers to initialize boolean values on a scope through ng-show.The boolean value checks and displays markup accordingly

Comment: Please check below my answer. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Trying2Learn will look into this also :)

Answer (score 0):

In your auth.js when user signIn (callback after user signIn success)

```
//In SignIn success callback.

$state.go('dashboard');//for state
$location.path("/dashboard");//for url dashboard
```

Hope it helps

Comment: If I use $location.path it changes the url almost immediately but the page changes only when the user is resolved.So it takes 3-5 seconds for that which is not intended :)

Comment: Yes. You can call `$location.path` when the user resolves in its success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use resolve to address this issue. When you are redirecting to "/" page. Just check in resolve section, whether the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in, redirect to dashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

> then it first shows sign in page then redirects to dashboard which I don't want.If I go from '/dashboard' to '/' then it should automatically go to dashboard page without going to sign in page.How do I achieve this

Really depends on your code. I recommend having the `login` route / logic maintained by the backend (check credentials there, and send a redirect to `/login` if not logged in.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--HTML code-->
<div ng-init="CheckIfLoggedIn()">
  <form id="login-form"> 
  ..............
  </form>
</div>

//in angular JS
$scope.CheckIfLoggedIn = function(){
    if (loggedinuser){
        $location.path("/dashboard");
    }
};
```

Comment: I have almost done the same thing with boolean value through controller :).Nevertheless the problem is solved, I had to change the main router file where I was setting signin and dashboard route.Thanks :)